# Как запустить приложение golang в скрытом режиме?

Tags: golang

Нужно что б консольное окно не было на экране ( и в свёрнутом виде тоже).
Что б приложение было только в процессах Windows.
Как такое сделать?

Comment: Точного ответа дать не могу, потому что не знаю Go, но точно знаю, что стоит копать в сторону сервисов Windows (запускать при загрузке как сервис).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При компиляции написать

```
go build -ldflags "-H windowsgui"
```

(на Windows)